# Ubuntu gets/has wrong private IP address

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openvpn, ip

When I log in via SSH to my Ubuntu server (current LTS 20.04), I get a greeting message with the eth0 private IP.

I now needed to change my IPs in my home network from the default 192.168.178.0/24 to 192.168.222.0/24

In the greeting message it still says

```
eth0 192.168.178.30
eth0 192.168.222.20
```

It can't have both IPs???

Reboot won't do anything.

I have ufw installed, but ufw reload won't do anything.

I also have OpenVPN and PiHole installed. It seems that something needs to be reconfigured, but I don't know which software still wants to connect via 192.168.178.30

Comment: Please edit your question adding the output of `ip addr` and the contents of any files in `/etc/netplan`, for a server typically `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`.

Comment: Any network node can have more IPv4 addresses on the same network interface, but only one may be primary address. The others must be marked as a "secondary" ones. Please, paste here output of the `ip addr` command and the files `/etc/netplan/01-*.yaml` and `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.conf` . They will show us the details. Somewhere, the original IP address is forgotten. You can find the file with it using the command `sudo grep -l -R "192.168.178.30" /etc/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what *netbat* said:

```
sudo grep -l -R "192.168.178.30" /etc/*
```

this showed me 3 conf-files (and a db file). I changed the respective conf-files so with nano (didn't care about the db-file). In one file (/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf) I also needed to change the routers IP address.

Now with a reboot, the wrong IP address is gone!